# C++: First-chance exception when assigning value to string in Object Pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, object, visual-studio-2012

Just as the title suggests, I am attempting to insert a value into an object pointer's string.

In my header, my object looks something as follows:

```
typedef struct d_tree
{
std::string name;
d_tree *parent;
std::vector<d_tree> dirs;
std::vector<t_file> files;
} tree_node;
```

(It's an assignment dealing with modeling a file and directory system for the curious.)
For the sake of my simplicity, I'm using strings and vectors (to avoid nuances of char * and double pointer arrays)

Now, for the head of this directory tree, I have in my source:

```
tree_node *G = (tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
getline(dirs, dirp);  //First should be main parent, or ./
G->name = dirp;
G->parent = NULL;
tree_node *top = G;
tree_node *curr = G;
```

The allocation runs fine and well, and the getline is only for reading some string data I'll be using...but once I hit the `G->name = ...`, My compiler (Using VS 12) yells:

```
" First-chance exception at 0x57AD11CE (msvcr110d.dll) in File_System.exe: 0xC0000005:
 Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. "
```

Upon looking at the local variables before the exception gets thrown, I notice a few things: the name variable in G has an  in the value column.

The parent variable also seems odd, but I won't worry about it just yet (esp. as I'm making it NULL, anyway..)

Any advice on how to alleviate this problem (preferably keeping strings, but understandable if no smooth solution exists) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `malloc` to allocate a `struct` of non-POD types. `malloc` only allocates memory, it does not *construct* the the non-POD members of the allocated `struct`.  Consequently, when you try to assign to that `struct`'s non-POD members, you're invoking each member type's assignment operator on a garbage object.

Use `new tree_node()` instead. (And also use `delete` instead of `free` to release the memory when you're done.  Or better yet, assuming that you have a true tree without cycles, use smart pointers to release the memory for you.)

Incidentally, you don't need to do

```
typedef struct tag { ... } typename;
```

in C++; just

```
struct typename { ... };
```

is equivalent.

Comment: And in general, you will have a difficult time finding a circumstance where `malloc` would be preferred over `new` in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use new, to create tree node, so that name's constructor will be called to initialize it.

```
//tree_node *G = (tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  tree_node *G = new tree_node;
```

This should work.
Although if you really need to allocate memory with malloc for some reason, you can use placement new.

```
 void* gptr = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));//Allocate memory
 tree_node *G = new(gptr) tree_node;//construct object in allocated memory
 //Do whatever you want with G
 G->~tree_node();//Explicitly call destrutor
 free(gptr);//free memory
```